# Django-ckeditor - странное поведение на разных машинах

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-admin

Запускаю один и тот же проект на домашней и на рабочей машине. Python --version и там, и там 3.5.1. Django - 1.9.0.
В чём может быть причина? Я что-то теряюсь.

Дома:

[image: На домашней машине]

На работе:

[image: На рабочей машине]

UPD: Кэш браузера почистил, не помогло. А статика и на работе, и дома используется одна и та же. Папка синхронизируется через Дропбокс.
В общем, проблема по-прежнему не решена.

Comment: Кэш браузера? :)

Comment: Никогда не работал с `django-ckeditor`, но может версии библы разные? Или статика не заинсталилась?

Answer (score 0):

Я подправил шаблон ckeditora: python3.5/site-packages/ckeditor/templates/ckeditor/widget.html.
Увеличил margin до 170

```
<div style="margin-left: 170px">
```

и стало ровно отображаться.